# Designing af PCB with an ISP header and a LED

Tags: eaglecad

This is my first project, it should be very simple. I'm trying to add an ISP header and a LED to a PCB, but I'm having doubts if it'll work. The problem is the GND connections .. the yellow line (in EAGLE) runs through the LED and then to the ISP header, then to the Attiny. Note that the board is not routed yet - but I have to follow the yellow lines.

That doesn't seem right.

Any points on how to solve this?

I would expect it to be: GND -> LED -> PB3 .. than GND -> ISP HEADER - GND (on Attiny) separate, not running through each other.

Pictures of schematic + board:

[image: Schematic]
[image: Board]

Comment: You don't have to follow the yellow lines. They are just drawn straight point-to-point so you know where your destination is. You can route whatever roundabout path you desire.

Comment: Thank you @whatsisname - I did not know this. I just looked at what the autorouter did, and kind of assumed that you were supposed to do that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yellow lines (called "airlines" in some PCB programs) show what points have to be connected together - they don't show the actual or required routing of the traces.

If you route the board manually, you look at the airlines to see what connections need to be made, then attempt to place tracks to make those connections, avoiding obstacles as necessary.  Your tracks don't have to follow the connection order indicated by the airlines, as long as all the required connections are made.  For example, if the airlines run from point A, through B, then C, to D, it is quite acceptable to route the track by going A, C, D, B if that is easier.

A note on your schematic:  The long line on the battery symbol is normally the positive terminal.

Pin 1 of a connector like JP1 is normally indicated by a square pad.

Comment: Hi Peter. Oh, I wasn't aware that I didn't have to follow the yellow lines (airlines) - I figured that because the autorouter seems to do this. Interesting in regards to the battery, I'll investigate this. My JP1 doesn't have a square pad tho (standard library PINHD-2X3), but I might try and find another library then, that has this indication. I have tried routing some of it now: http://s7.postimg.org/c5ve29oru/Screen_Shot_2015_10_12_at_21_39_35.jpg

Comment: "Airlines" are called "rat's nest" in some other programs.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff Hmm. In EAGLE, when I select "Router Manually", it tells me "airwire" - but I also have a Rat's nest which does something entirely different as far as I know (ground pours?) - is there a common name, that everyone will know what is (airwire, airline). I'd like to know the terminology :)